# How to load a webpage in an ovally inside a SwiftUI App vs loading in safari

Tags: swiftui, webkit

The functionality I'm looking to create is what the ESPN app does when you click on one of its alerts... it loads the app but instead of formatting the view it loads a Safari view over the app that can be tapped away (honestly I hate it in that instance but in ones like these it would work great.)

current code for reference

```
Button(action: {
                openURL(URL(string: "linkhere")!)
    }) {
                Image("LISTENMENU")
            }
```

Am I going to need to setup another view and build the webkitview myself or can this functionality be specified another way? (perhaps by tinkering with the openURL string

Comment: The only thing I've found thats close to this is: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller However is not SwiftUI compatible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) (which is from UIKit) into SwiftUI, since it isn't possible to do this natively right now. You should use [UIViewControllerRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable) to do this.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SafariServices

struct MyView: View {
    @State var showStackoverflow:Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.showStackoverflow = true }) {
            Text("Open stackoverflow")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$showStackoverflow) {
            SFSafariViewWrapper(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")!)
        }
    }
}
struct SFSafariViewWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<Self>) -> SFSafariViewController {
        return SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SFSafariViewWrapper>) {
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it with simple way. This is working with SwiftUI as well.

```
   UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
```